Setting Maximum Packet Size up to which GRO can combine in the Linux Kernel
In a Linux environment, Generic Receive Offload (GRO) helps improve network performance by merging multiple packets into a larger one, reducing CPU overhead.
Now we want to control the maximum size of the packet that GRO can combine.
Is there a way to configure this maximum packet size? Which kernel or system parameters need to be adjusted to set this limit?
Moreover, does the MTU (maximum transmission unit) of the network interface affect the maximum GRO size?
Edit: The system is Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Any help would be appreciated.

For the 1st question:

Is there a way to configure this maximum packet size?

Found [net-next] gro: add ability to control gro max packet size which is a patch from January 2022 in which the description starts with:

Eric Dumazet suggested to allow users to modify max GRO packet size.
We have seen GRO being disabled by users of appliances (such as wifi access points) because of claimed bufferbloat issues, or some work arounds in sch_cake, to split GRO/GSO packets.
Instead of disabling GRO completely, one can chose to limit the maximum packet size of GRO packets, depending on their latency constraints.
This patch adds a per device gro_max_size attribute that can be changed with ip link command.

I'm not entirely sure which distributions this patch is available in, so had a look at a sample.
Is present in Ubuntu 24.04
On a Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS system with Kernel 6.8.0-45-generic ip link show has gro_max_size initially shown as 65536 on an Ethernet device:
$ ip -d link show eno1
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ec:b1:d7:3e:5f:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0  allmulti 0 minmtu 68 maxmtu 9000 addrgenmode none numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 tso_max_size 65536 tso_max_segs 65535 gro_max_size 65536 parentbus pci parentdev 0000:00:19.0 
    altname enp0s25

Changed the value to 16000:
$ sudo ip link set dev eno1 gro_max_size 16000

And the value reads back as changed:
$ ip -d link show eno1
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ec:b1:d7:3e:5f:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0  allmulti 0 minmtu 68 maxmtu 9000 addrgenmode none numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 tso_max_size 65536 tso_max_segs 65535 gro_max_size 16000 parentbus pci parentdev 0000:00:19.0 
    altname enp0s25

Doesn't seem fully supported in AlmaLinux 8.10
On an AlmaLinux 8.10 system with Kernel 4.18.0-553.22.1.el8_10.x86_64 doesn't seem to be supported.
Can set the value on an Ethernet device with no error reported:
$ sudo ip link set dev eno1 gro_max_size 16000

However, ip link show doesn't report a value for gro_max_size before or after attempting to change the value:
$ ip -d link show eno1
5: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:60:24:93:38:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 minmtu 68 maxmtu 9000 addrgenmode none numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 parentbus pci parentdev 0000:00:1f.6 
    altname enp0s31f6

I haven't checked if it is the AlmaLinux 8.10 Kernel and/or user space ip link command which doesn't support the gro_max_size attribute.

Try a HWE kernel?

On which linux, we can apply patch? Tried in many 5. and 6. but facing issues.
